# Count all type devices by week

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a table:

```
idint(11) NOT NULL
type varchar(64) NOT NULL
created_on datetime NOT NULL
```

Can I count all type devices (iSO, Android...) by week in one query when use doctrine2?

Sample output:

```
Week iOS Android Other
1     4    5       6
2     3    5       9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely possible, using methods similar to that detailed in [Output Sum of some column in week intervals throughout a year, week dates consistent with day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539719/output-sum-of-some-column-in-week-intervals-throughout-a-year-week-dates-consis/15569190#15569190) however not easily in the output you described.  The best way to handle this will be to do a SELECT, grouping on WEEK and TYPE.  I.e.

```
SELECT

    -- Get the week and month of each row
    YEAR(created_on) AS Year,
    WEEK(created_on) AS Week,
    type

    -- Count how many rows are in this group
    COUNT(*) AS frequency

FROM yourTable AS yt

-- Order by month and then week, so that week 4 in Jan comes before week 4 in Feb
GROUP BY
    Year ASC,
    Week ASC,
    type ASC
```

This would give output such as

```
Year    Week    Type       frequency
2013    1       'iOS'      4
2013    1       'Android'  5
2013    1       'Other'    6
2013    2       'iOS'      3
2013    2       'Android'  5
2013    2       'Other'    9
```